# Why does using asyncio.ensure_future for long jobs instead of await run so much quicker?

Tags: python-asyncio

I am downloading jsons from an api and am using the asyncio module. The crux of my question is, with the following event loop as implemented as this:

```py
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
main_task = asyncio.ensure_future( klass.download_all() )
loop.run_until_complete( main_task )
```

and `download_all()` implemented like this instance method of a class, which already has downloader objects created and available to it, and thus calls each respective `download` method:

```py
async def download_all(self):
    """ Builds the coroutines, uses asyncio.wait, then sifts for those still pending, loops """
    ret = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        pending = []

        for downloader in self._downloaders:
            pending.append( asyncio.ensure_future( downloader.download(session) ) )

        while pending:
            dne, pnding= await asyncio.wait(pending)
            ret.extend( [d.result() for d in dne] )

            # Get all the tasks, cannot use "pnding"
            tasks = asyncio.Task.all_tasks()
            pending = [tks for tks in tasks if not tks.done()]
            # Exclude the one that we know hasn't ended yet (UGLY)
            pending = [t for t in pending if not t._coro.__name__ == self.download_all.__name__]

    return ret
```

Why is it, that in the downloaders' `download` methods, when instead of the `await` syntax, I choose to do `asyncio.ensure_future` instead, it runs way faster, that is more seemingly "asynchronously" as I can see from the logs.

This works because of the way I have set up detecting all the tasks that are still pending, and not letting the `download_all` method complete, and keep calling `asyncio.wait`.

I thought that the `await` keyword allowed the event loop mechanism to do its thing and share resources efficiently? How come doing it this way is faster? Is there something wrong with it? For example:

```py
async def download(self, session):
    async with session.request(self.method, self.url, params=self.params) as response:
        response_json = await response.json()

    # Not using await here, as I am "supposed" to
    asyncio.ensure_future( self.write(response_json, self.path) ) 
    return response_json

async def write(self, res_json, path):
    # using aiofiles to write, but it doesn't (seem to?) support direct json
    # so converting to raw text first
    txt_contents = json.dumps(res_json, **self.json_dumps_kwargs);
    async with aiofiles.open(path, 'w') as f:
        await f.write(txt_contents)
```

With full code implemented and a real API, I was able to download 44 resources in 34 seconds, but when using await it took more than three minutes (I actually gave up as it was taking so long).

Answer (score 0):

When you do `await` in each iteration of `for` loop it will await to download every iteration.
When you do `ensure_future` on the other hand it doesn't it creates task to download all the files and then awaits all of them in second loop.